How to fix artists getting cut out when saving a figure in matplotlib?
I want to make a plot with legend and some text with info on the side. This figure is supposed to be in a pdf with other similar figures. (This will be done using matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages but first I need to fix the problem with the cutting out which happens in both scenarios.)
When I execute the code in the IPython Notebook I get an image of a figure with nothing cut out but when I try to save the figure the legend and the text are cut out
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title("Data")
ax.barh(["1", "2", "3"], [20, 10, 30], label="fresh data")
t = fig.text(-0.1, 1, "Hello")
l = fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.93, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5))
plt.savefig("test.png")

The image in the notebook:
image without cut out elements
The saved image:
image with cut out elements
I expected the saved image to be like the shown in the notebook. I tried fixing the problem using a constrained layout and using set_in_layout() but the result was the same as before.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout="constrained")
plt.title("Data")
ax.barh(["1", "2", "3"], [20, 10, 30], label="fresh data")
t = fig.text(-0.1, 1, "Hello")
t.set_in_layout(True)
l = fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.93, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5))
l.set_in_layout(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")

Versions:
matplotlib 3.7.1
Python 3.11.3
IPython 8.11.0

add bbox_inches='tight' to savefig
